# Print out each character randomly

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, random, char

I am creating a small game where the user will have hints(Characters of a string) to guess the word of a string. I have the code to see each individual character of the string, but is it possible that I can see those characters printed out randomly?

```
string str("TEST");
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
cout <<" "<< str[i];
```

output:T E S T 
desired  sample output: E T S T

Comment: Did you check `std::shuffle` ?

Comment: You probably want to check that your shuffle did more than swap the first and last "T". In other words, shuffle until your shuffled word is different from the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) on the string:

```
random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end());
```

**Edits**:
C++11 onwards use:

```
auto engine = std::default_random_engine{};
shuffle ( begin(str), end(str), engine );
```

Comment: `random_shuffle` is deprecated from C++14 and will be removed from C++ 17 dude

Comment: Oh Thanks @Danh for the info.

Comment: Right idea, though.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample n-combination of n-element set is also a permutation of n-element set.

Comment: @khôinguyễn you're free to give your own answer dude

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to generate the letters randomly.

```
    const int stl = str.size();
    int stl2 = stl;
    while (stl2 >= 0)
    {
        int r = rand() % stl;
        if (str[r] != '0')
        {
            cout<<" "<<str[r];
            str[r] = '0';
            stl2--;
        }
    }
```

This code basically generates the random number based on the size of the String and then prints the character placed at that particular position of the string.
To avoid the reprinting of already printed character, I have converted the character printed to "0", so next time same position number is generated, it will check if the character is "0" or not.

If you need to preserve the original string, then you may copy the string to another variable and use it in the code.

**Note:** It is assumed that string will contain only alphabetic characters and so to prevent repetition, "0" is used. If your string may contain numbers, you may use a different character for comparison purpose